# Access 2010: filter from multiple records in memo field?

Tags: filter, conditional-statements, ms-access-2010, memo

I've poured through here looking for an answer to this, but haven't found it anywhere.

I have an Access 2010 database with two tables:

- one with about 14k codes and definitions(all five digits, including some letters).
- one with a total of 900k records, each record containing pairs of combinations of these same codes (each code in the pair in a separate column, CODE1 and CODE2)

When our office gets a new project, I have to check to see if the codes used in the project match any one of those pairs of combinations. Some projects only use two codes, but some can have as many as twenty or more.

I would like to be able to enter in all the codes used in any one project into either a text field or memo field, then have Access show me if a combination exists between **any** of those codes.

Example: If I have 5 codes, I want to see if any of the 900k pairs of codes contains **ANY** 1 of those 5 codes in **both** CODE1 **and** CODE2.

Anyone know how to do this, or if this is even possible in Access 2010?

Answer (score 0):

No, I think you want another table with the code IDs (2-20) for each project, then you can cross join it with itself to get your set of pairs, then inner join it with your pairs table, 900k